# Marketing Cloud SSH Key Generation: Inconsistency between PuTTY and ssh-keygen

Tags: putty, openssh, ssh-keys, salesforce

After spending two months back and forth with Salesforce Support, I have finally worked out that in order to upload an SSH key in Key Management, you have to use 
PuTTYgen, not `ssh-keygen` (on Mac).

Is someone able to explain to me how I can get `ssh-keygen` to generate the same kind of private RSA key as PuTTY?

Here's an example key that PuTTYgen created (and that Salesforce Marketing Cloud will happily accept):

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

And here's the key that `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048` is giving me:

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Quick observation says that the `BEGIN RSA` and `BEGIN OPENSSH` titles are different. It also appears that PuTTY does it's line-breaks at 65 characters and `ssh-keygen` breaks the line at 71 characters.

The exact instructions I used for creating the key in PuttyGen are as follows:

1. Download [PuTTYgen](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html)
2. Click *Generate* and move the mouse to create randomness
3. Once the key is generated, don't *Save Private Key*, but go to the *Conversions* menu and click *Export OpenSSH Key*
4. Leave the passcode blank and save as a **.ppk* file
5. Upload to Key Management in Marketing Cloud.

Does anyone knows a trick to do this with `ssh-keygen` (so I don't have to keep borrowing a Windows machine)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Latest versions of OpenSSH `ssh-keygen` (7.8 and newer) generate keys in a new format (`BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY`).

Your software (Salesforce Marketing Cloud) does not seem to support that format.

Use [`-m PEM` flag](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-keygen#m), to make new `ssh-keygen` generate the keys in the old format (like `BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY`):

```
ssh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa -b 2048
```

You can also use `ssh-keygen` to convert your existing key in the new format to the old format by "abusing" the [`-p` switch](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-keygen#p):

```
ssh-keygen -p -f file -m PEM -P passphrase -N passphrase
```

(if the key is not encrypted with a passphrase, use `""` instead of `passphrase`)

---

PuTTYgen can also generate both formats. But, unless you use the command with *"(force new file format)"* or unless you generate Ed25519 key (not supported by the old format), it defaults to the old format. That was also the [behavior of `ssh-keygen` in 6.5–7.7](https://superuser.com/q/1455735/213663).

Btw, there's also a [command-line Linux `puttygen`](https://manpages.debian.org/stable/putty-tools/puttygen.1.en.html).

Comment: THANK YOU! That totally works.